# What are the cases whereby EXCEPT and DISTINCT are different?

Tags: sql

Looking into my notes for introduction to databases, I have stumbled upon a case that i do not understand (Between `except` and `distinct`).

It says so in my notes that:

> The two queries below have the same results, but this will not be the case in general.

First query:

```
Select c.first_name,c.last_name,c.email
FROM customers as c
WHERE c.country = 'Japan'

EXCEPT

Select c.first_name,c.last_name,c.email
FROM customers as c
WHERE c.last_name LIKE 'D%';
```

Second query:

```
Select DISTINCT  c.first_name,c.last_name,c.email
FROM customers as c 
WHERE c.country = 'Japan' AND NOT (c.last_name LIKE 'D%');
```

Could anyone provide me some insights as to what are cases whereby the results would differ?

Comment: The first query would still return duplicates, and you are sort of comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry. It was a typo. Both are Japan.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 selects first, last & email from customers who are from Japan and whose last names do not start with D.

Number 2 selects first, last & email, where no two records have all 3 fields the same, where the customers are from Singapore and their last names do not begin with D.

I suppose I can imagine a table where these would yield the same results, but I don't think it would ever appear except in very contrived circumstances.

```
Joe Smith jsmith@abc.com Japan
Joe Smith jsmith@abc.com Singapore
```

Would be one of them. Both queries would yield `Joe Smith jsmith@abc.com`. Another case would be if no-one was from either country or everyone's last name started with D, then they would both yield nothing.

None of this is tested, and the EXCEPT statement is something I've read about but never had occasion to use.

Answer (score 0):

The first is looking at Japan, the second at Singapore, so I don't see why these would generally -- or specifically -- return the same data.

Even if the countries were the same you have another issue with `NULL` values.  So, if your data looks like this:

```
first_name   last_name    email   country
   xxx          NULL         a     Japan
```

Your first query would return the row.  The second would not.